# Is it possible assign printer when run this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload=function(){self.print();} 
</script>
```

Dear all,

how can I assign a printer for this script or just print out PDF file. because I always have other document need to print, I don't want always set default printer. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**No!** you can't bypass printer options. its defined in the user's OS.